# Is it possible to edit the Backstage in Word 365?

Tags: ms-word, office365

We are in the process of moving from Office 2010 to Office 365.

One of our major add-ins in Word is a Startup template that has a customUI which updates the Backstage to hide the standard "New" template and replace it with our own. For example:

```
<backstage>    
   <tab idMso="TabNew" visible="false"/>
   <tab id="MyNew" label="My New" insertAfterMso="TabNew">
```

The document relating to this is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2010/ee815851(v=office.14)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

When we try and add the template to the Word365 Startup folder the "My New" menu item appears at the very bottom of the Backstage, and the "TabNew" is still visible.

Have Microsoft completely removed the ability to set customise the Backstage through XML?

Comment: I haven't looked at this in Office 365 but my first thought is that the tab's `idMso` might be different in that version? That would be a reasonable explanation for the behavior you describe. Have you checked the list of IdMso for Office 365?

Comment: That's my gut feeling as well, but I'm failing to find a list of the new idMSos...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The backstage can still be edited through *customUI.xml* it's just that the names have been changed.

[This answer on microsoft](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/2010-to-365-migration-best-practice/d5153d0e-09e3-4cdd-88f4-36e57df7abfa) gives the new name needed, and links to a blogpost that highlights the name changes in 2013, which mostly still work.

Answer (score 0):

The Backstage UI differs significantly in Office 365: there is no longer any option to select any of one's own templates, only "Blank document" and ones available from Microsoft ("online"). Thus, this Backstage tab is no longer available for customization. The information has been removed from the `wordcontrols.xlsx` for Office 365/16, which also means it can't be referenced for location or hidden (which is rather disturbing).

Download: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=50745

You might want to contact Microsoft TechNet support to find out if there's any way to suppress that menu item. Perhaps with a group policy in network administration.